# Overleaf shortcuts don't work in vim mode

Tags: overleaf

In Overleaf, I can choose 3 modes for the editor, one of them being 'vim'. In this mode, the overleaf editor almost behaves like vim. But the Overleaf shortcut to recompile the code (`Ctrl + .`) doesn't work in vim mode.

Comment: In overleaf, I can chose 3 modes for the editor, one of them being 'vim'. In this mode, the overleaf editor almost behaves like vim. I don't know anything about  'atom' plugin on overleaf.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Overleaf. If you are sure the problem is at their end and not yours, you should contact them and report the problem. This might be off-topic here.

Comment: I agree with moewe. But probably if it shall behave like vim, it is likely that you have vim-like commands to compile.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a cofounder at Overleaf. You can trigger a manual preview refresh with `:w` — that is, how you'd usually save the current file. (We automatically save your file every few seconds, so the usual meaning of `:w` isn't applicable.)